# Use of boolean value in custom angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make use of a directives, however I'm facing an issue with passing through a boolean value. When I evaluate my page this is what I get as an error:

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression
>   [{{app.isNew}}] starting at [{app.isNew}}].

The code I'm using is as follows:

**home.html**

```
<featured-app app-title="{{app.title}}" app-is-new={{app.isNew}}></featured-app>
```

**home.js**

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.app.title = "App name";
    $scope.app.isNew = true;
}]);
```

**featuredApp.js**

```
app.directive('featuredApp', function() {
   return {
       templateUrl: 'directives/templates/featuredApp.html',
       scope: {
           appTitle: '@',
           appIsNew: '='
        }
   };
});
```

**featuredApp.html**

```
<h2>{{appTitle}} <span class="label label-default" ng-show="{{appIsNew}}">New</span></h2>
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting the error above? I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html to:

**home.html**

```
<featured-app app-title="{{app.title}}" app-is-new="app.isNew"></featured-app>
```

or change **featuredApp.js** to:

```
app.directive('featuredApp', function() {
   return {
       templateUrl: 'directives/templates/featuredApp.html',
       scope: {
           appTitle: '@',
           appIsNew: '@'
        }
   };
});
```

Above depends on your requirement. One is one-way binded other is two-way. Though you have to also do the following change:

**featuredApp.html**

```
<h2>{{appTitle}} <span class="label label-default" ng-show="appIsNew">New</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<featured-app app-title="{{app.title}}" app-is-new={{app.isNew}}></featured-app>
```

With:

```
<featured-app app-title="app.title" app-is-new=app.isNew></featured-app>
```

And:

```
appTitle: '@',
```

With:

```
appTitle: '=',
```

The problem was that you were using `{{}}` in places where angular expects a variable name.